# MockMVC test Status expected:<201> but was:<404>

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import preproject.underdog.answer.dto.answer.AnswerPostDto;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(value = AnswerController.class)
//@AutoConfigureRestDocs
@MockBean(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.class)
public class AnswerController {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("답변 글 작성 테스트")
    void postAnswer() throws Exception {
        AnswerPostDto post = new AnswerPostDto("테스트", 1L, 1L);
        String content = gson.toJson(post);

        ResultActions actions =
                mockMvc.perform(
                        post("/answers")
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(content)
                );

        actions
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import preproject.underdog.answer.dto.answer.AnswerPostDto;
import preproject.underdog.answer.dto.answer.AnswerRespDto;
import preproject.underdog.answer.mapper.AnswerMapper;
import preproject.underdog.answer.service.AnswerService;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/answers")
@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnswerController {

    private final AnswerService answerService;
    private final AnswerMapper answerMapper;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity postAnswer(@Valid @RequestBody AnswerPostDto answerPostDto) {

        AnswerRespDto answerRespDto = new AnswerRespDto(1L,"테스트",1L,1L,1L,  LocalDateTime.of(2023, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0),LocalDateTime.of(2023, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(answerRespDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Here's my codes first,

I tried make Rest Docs first, but I faced a lot of errors, so I just started to try pass the MockMVC test first.

So I gotta got 201 response from that, but I only got 404 error

### here's my log.

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
HTTP Method = POST
Request URI = /answers
Parameters = {}
Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"49"]
Body = {"content":"테스트","userId":1,"questionId":1}
Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
Async started = false
Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
Type = null

ModelAndView:
View name = null
View = null
Model = null

FlashMap:
Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
Status = 404
Error message = null
Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
Content type = null
Body =
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
Cookies = []
```

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity postAnswer(@Valid @RequestBody AnswerPostDto answerPostDto) {
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I even tried to changed the code to get only 201 response like this

but it still gave me 404 error

What should I do?? thanks

Comment: Your test wouldn't even run as you are missing dependencies, also remove the `@Validated` from the controller class, that doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I deleted all and wrote slowly and carefully again, then I got 201 response. thanks for your advice!